# Client Server in C programming undefined reference

Tags: c, reference, server, client, undefined

I am getting errors while compiling my simple client server program in C:

```
undefined reference to 'socket'
undefined reference to 'htons'
undefined reference to 'bind'
undefined reference to 'listen'
undefined reference to 'accept'
undefined reference to 'recv'
undefined reference to '_impure_ptr'
```

My code for the client:

```
#include <stdio.h>              /* perror() */
#include <stdlib.h>             /* atoi() */
#include <sys/types.h>          
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <unistd.h>         /* read() */
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int clientSocket,remotePort, status=0;
    struct hostent *hostPtr=NULL;
    struct sockaddr_in serverName={0};
    char buffer[256]="";
    char *remoteHost=NULL;

    if(3!=argc){
        fprintf(stderr,"Usage %s <serverHost <serverPort>\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    remoteHost=argv[1];
    remotePort=atoi(argv[2]);
    clientSocket=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
    if(-1==clientSocket){
        perror("socket()");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     * need to resolve the remote server name or IP address
     */

     hostPtr=gethostbyname(remoteHost);
     if(NULL==hostPtr){
         hostPtr=gethostbyaddr(remoteHost,strlen(remoteHost),AF_INET);
         if(NULL==hostPtr){
             perror("Error resolving server address ");
             exit(1);
         }
     }
     serverName.sin_family=AF_INET;
     serverName.sin_port=htons(remotePort);
     (void)memcpy(&serverName.sin_addr,hostPtr->h_addr,hostPtr->h_length);
     status=connect(clientSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&serverName,
                    sizeof(serverName));
    if(-1==status){
        perror("connect()");
        exit(1);
    }

    /*
     *Client application specific code goes here
     *
     *e.g. receive messages from server, respond, etc.
     */
     while(0<(status=read(clientSocket,buffer,sizeof(buffer)-1)))
         printf("%d: %s",status,buffer);
     if(-1==status)perror("read()");
     close(clientSocket);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Put `#define _POSIX_VERSION  200809L` on top of all, even before the includes and try again.

Comment: Which operating system is this on?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi, I think the problem hasn't anything in common with what you describe.  The error is a linker error, and many non posix systems (like e.g. windows) also have `socket(2)`, `htons(3)`, `bind(2)`, etc. system calls and functions.

Comment: @karlcides, please, can you edit your question and describe the command used to compile and get those errors.  And try to show also the exact format of error lines, as I'm afraid these have been edited by you (it's common to reference the source file and/or source line where the error was found)

Comment: @LuisColorado It was a first, fast guess, because it is a typical error if you use GCC with options that press it to go with the C-standards more strictly (e.g.: `-std=c11`). If you search Google for the errors they will tell you that you have to include all of the necessary headers and those are all there amd than you are stuck if you don't know about the Posix problem. It is just a matter of C&P to try it out, so I put it in a comment. If that didn't help the OP should follow your recommendations and post the command that tried to compile it.